# UIAccessibility change UITableView voiceover announcements (row # of #)

Tags: ios, tableview, accessibility, voiceover, uiaccessibility

With VoiceOver enabled a user can use a 3 finger swipe gesture to scroll TableViews.
VoiceOver verbally announces to the user a phrase indicating their location on the tableview i.e. the rows that are visible such as  "Rows 1 to 4 of 5".

I would like to override this verbal prompt and get voiceover to announce something else to the user.

Comment: What are you trying to announce? Give us a little more detail and we can come up with a solution for you.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use [UIScrollViewAccessibilityDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollViewAccessibilityDelegate_Protocol/index.html) and implement the method [-accessibilityScrollStatusForScrollView:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollViewAccessibilityDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIScrollViewAccessibilityDelegate/accessibilityScrollStatusForScrollView:)

**Example**

```
- (NSString *)accessibilityScrollStatusForScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    return @"Your text";
}
```

Comment: From iOS 6 on this is the right thing to do. Much simpler than the accepted answer.

Comment: And there is a corresponding UIPickerViewAccessibilityDelegate, that works as you would expect. The default VoiceOvers for these two UI elements leave a lot to be desired.

Answer (score 11):

You can't change *only* the message. You will have to override `accessibilityScroll:` and do the scrolling and then post the scroll announcement (at least I don't know any other way). It isn't super hard though.

### What to do

Since you have a table view you can scroll to a certain row using `scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:`. You could decide that one accessibility element is X number of rows. In that case you get the set of visible rows from the table view and add or remove X to the row of the last or first cell (depending on if the scroll is up or down).

Finally to announce the that the table view did scroll you should post a "page scrolled" notification and pass the text to be read. Finally you should return `YES` to say that you handled the scrolling (if you don't then the event will continue to propagate).

### Example implementation

A basic implementation could look something like this (I'm making some assumptions that may change depending on your code, like that there is only one section):

```
- (BOOL)accessibilityScroll:(UIAccessibilityScrollDirection)direction 
{
    BOOL isScrollingUp = NO;
    switch (direction) {
        case UIAccessibilityScrollDirectionUp: {
            isScrollingUp = YES;
        } break;

        case UIAccessibilityScrollDirectionDown: {
            isScrollingUp = NO;
        } break;

        default:
            // These cases are not handled
            return NO;
    }

    NSInteger numberOfCellsToScroll = 5; // Any number you'd like

    NSInteger newRow = -1;
    if (isScrollingUp) {
        newRow = [self.tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows][0].row - numberOfCellsToScroll;
    } else {
        newRow = [[self.tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows] lastObject].row + numberOfCellsToScroll;
    }

    [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:newRow inSection:0] 
                          atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle 
                                  animated:YES];

    UIAccessibilityPostNotification(UIAccessibilityPageScrolledNotification,
                                    @"YOUR CUSTOM TEXT FOR THE SCROLL HERE");

    return YES; // We handled the scroll
}
```

Comment: I'm curious, though: does this mean that when a user does the 3-finger scroll up or down, that I can use this override to completely control how many rows up or down the tableview moves? Up to this point I've assumed that how far up or down I drag my 3 fingers determines how far the table scrolls.

Comment: @MusiGenesis Yes, the 3 finger scroll is more like a swipe gesture than a pan gesture. The user does one scroll up or down and you change to the next or previous "page".