# UICollectionView Section Headers as Accessibility Headers

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uiaccessibility

*I have two questions regarding accessibility and UICollectionViews that I'm hoping to get some expert help with. The other question, regarding Voice Over read order, is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16289496/uicollectionviewflowlayout-voice-over-reads-items-out-of-order-with-flow-layout). I've created a [sample project](https://github.com/jose-ibanez/CollectionViewAccessibility) demonstrating both issues.*

I have a `UICollectionView` where I'm providing custom section headers. These section headers are accessibility elements and have the accessibility trait `UIAccessibilityTraitHeader` set. When Voice Over is enabled, and the user is swiping horizontally through the collection, the header is announced properly, and it is even declared as a header.  However, if the user swipes up or down to the next header, Voice Over will only jump to another header if it is visible.  I'm assuming this is because when a view isn't visible in a collection view, it's removed from the view hierarchy and Voice Over no longer knows it exists.

You can pull [this example project](https://github.com/jose-ibanez/CollectionViewAccessibility), run it, enable voice over, and use the dial to set the swipe up/down to headings to view the issue.

**Is there a way I can allow the user to jump to a header that is not currently visible?** Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: it's 2021 and I'm running into the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You might have to use the `scrollToItemAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:` property of the `UICollectionView` to scroll the header into view before VoiceOver can read it.

You can find out which `indexPath` you are currently at via `indexPathForItemAtPoint:` using the position of where they touched within the collection view and then you know which section comes after.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. I don't think that when Voice Over is enabled you receive tap notifications in the traditional way; however, I can hook into when a cell receives accessibility focus. Unfortunately, I don't know how to detect when the user has swiped up or down to know when to scroll to the previous or next section. I'm pretty sure `accessibilityScroll` is the three-finger scroll gesture, not the one finger swipe I'm looking for.

Comment: I honestly haven't used Voice Over enough to tell you.  This should help you with how to hook my code above into the callback: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15616144/308315